# Getting array of option closing tags after partial containing options

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, partial-views, partials

I have dynamic select boxes in my view

**../diys/_form.htmlerb**

```
      ...
      <%= f.fields_for :attached_vehicles do |av| %>
        <p>Select make</p>
        <%= av.select :make, options_for_select(@makes.collect { |make|[make.make_name, make.id] }, 0), {}, { id: 'makes_select' } %><br>
        <p>Select model</p>
        <%= av.select :model, (render "make_models/make_model"), {}, { id: 'models_select' } %><br>
      <% end %>
      ...
```

which launches coffee script on change

**../assets/javascripts/diys.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#makes_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_make_models',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        make_id: $("#makes_select option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic make select OK!")
```

which launches

**../views/diys/update_make_models.coffee**

```
$("#models_select").empty()
   .append("<%= escape_javascript(render "make_models/make_model") %>")
```

which renders partial

**../views/make_models/make_model.html.erb**

```
<%= @models.collect do |models| %>
  <option val="<%= models.id %>"><%= models.make_model_name %></option>
<% end %>
```

and everything works great, except in view I get an array of option closing tags inside select element after option elements
[**like this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFhcx.jpg).

Here's also some parts from my

**../controllers/diys_controller.rb**

```
...
def update_make_models
  @models = MakeModel.where("make_id = ?", params[:make_id])
  respond_to do |format|
      format.js
  end
end

def new
  @diy = Diy.new
  @step = @diy.steps.new
  @diy.attached_vehicles.new
  @step.add_images_to_steps.new
  @makes = Make.all
  @models = MakeModel.where("make_id = ?", Make.first.id)
end
...
```

Comment: why are you requesting as script and not html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= @models.collect do |models| %>
  <option val="<%= models.id %>"><%= models.make_model_name %></option>
<% end %>
```

Should be

```
<% @models.collect do |models| %>
  <option val="<%= models.id %>"><%= models.make_model_name %></option>
<% end %>
```

When you use the <%= %> it prints the result in the template file. Make sure to leave it out of your loops or you will get these artifacts.

Here is some [great documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_template_erb.html#tags) on ERB tags.